# Unable to load smart contract using web3j on android

Tags: web3j, android

What I'my trying to do is to load already deployed smart contract and interact with it. The problem is that after my credentials are being created properly, the error is being catched but the message is empty. I' m new to adnroid, and totally don't know how to make it work. I will upload more infos but don't actually know what are exactly needed. I would be very greatfull for help.

[image: My code]

Comment: I see 2 things that I would start with. First you have deprecated method and variables in your code, you can double check if they are working properly or it's just your editor showing warning. Second this might sound silly, but in your infura URL are you including the ID from your infura application? Are you replacing "idinfura" string with your actual project ID? Just making sure you didn't copy paste this from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer, the problem was actually not with the Project.load method but with .send() when using Web3j on android you have to use sendAsync().get() so the problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually not with the Project.load method but with .send() when using Web3j on android you have to use sendAsync().get() to make it work. So the problem is solved.